# Background-color changes the color of an element, not the actual background - how to overcome this?

Tags: css

I'm trying to add background to the following element (marked red): https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXq46.jpg

It's code looks like this:

```
.otfm-sp__title::after, .otfm-sp__title::before {
    background-color: #777;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    left: 16px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(.42,0,.58,1);
    transition: all .2s cubic-bezier(.42,0,.58,1);
    width: 14px;
}
```

When I change the background-color property, what's changing is the color of the plus icon, not it's actual background. I feel like I've tried everything - does anyone have any idea how to overcome it and add an actual background to this little "+" icon?

Comment: You've forgotten to include the code for the image. We can't see how the button is created and captioned.

Comment: That plus is made up from pseudo elements, think of it like as two tiny rectangle `div`s drawing the horizontal and vertical line of the `+`. To add a background you will need to use a wrapping element (Ideally, you need to add the HTML, otherwise we can't really help)

Comment: @kacperrro99 - No. You should have read the instructions already in the Help Centre. In them, you'd see directions to include your code in the question. Links can wither and die with time, rendering the question useless.

Comment: I'm not sure which code should I include. I went through all the plugin's files but I cant find any html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing the link, I've seen the markup and the problem is that you have used the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements as the plus sign.

To achieve the effect you want you can use one of the following two methods.

method:1

```
  /*apply box-shadow to one of the pseudo elements*/
   
  ::before {
     box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px red;
  }
```

method:2
In the html you can create a separate div for the plus sign like this..

```css
.plus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="plus"> + </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that :)